# Computing KL Divergence for distributions over sets

Tags: computational-statistics, approximation, kullback-leibler

I have a distribution over a set of (hundreds of) discrete terms, and I'd like to describe the difference between

I see a couple of options, and none seems really attractive:

1. Take the KL divergence where the distribution is defined over the power set of the terms. With 100's of terms, this is computationally infeasible and the distribution will have a lot of zeroes, requiring some large amount of smoothing.
2. Take the sum of the KL divergences of the marginal distribution of each term. This assumes a level of independence that doesn't exist in the data.
3. Factor or cluster the target and base distributions into lower dimensions and take the KL of the dense, lower-dimensional representation.

Is there a standard technique here?